# Insert data type JSON in lighthouse php

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I´m working in back graphql API with Laravel and Lighthouse.

I have a table with a column named "config" that stores json data.

I´m trying to create a new register to that table.

I have a mutation:

```
createOrderTemplate(name: String!, config: JSON!): OrderTemplate @create
```

The schema is:

```
type OrderTemplate {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    config: JSON! 
}
```

I´ve tried the mutation in graphql-playground

```
mutation{
  createOrderTemplate(
    name:"SomeName",
    config:
    [{
      "w_name": "Name1",
      "w_code": "001",
      "place": "Place1",
      "job": "job1",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "name3",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "name4",
          "quantity": 2
        }
      ]
    },
{
      "w_name": "Name2",
      "w_code": "002",
      "place": "Place2",
      "job": "job2",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "name3"
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "name4",
          "quantity": 2
        }
      ]
    }]
){
    id
    name
    config
  }
```

When I typed this I get an error, all is colored red and it does not execute anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to run that query in Insomnia, so you could see the exception that is thrown.

Moreover, I don't think that `config` gets a valid JSON value. Try first with a simple JSON like `{key: 'value'}`

Comment: I´ll try! Thank you!

Comment: I´ve tried as yoy say with the following mutation:  mutation{
    createOrderTemplate(
      name:"Name"
      config:[{w_code:"Name Surname"}]
    ){
      id
      name
      config
    }
  }  But I get the message:  "debugMessage": "Field \"createOrderTemplate\" argument \"config\" requires type JSON, found [{w_code: \"Name Surname\"}]; array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\NodeList given",
      "message": "Internal server error"

Comment: I can put JSON directly on my data base with the schema [ {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key": [ {"key":"value"},{"key":"value"} ],  {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key": [ {"key":"value"},{"key":"value"} ] } ] but It doesn´t work on my back. Is there any way to do that? I really need it

Comment: Try with
`mutation{ createOrderTemplate( name:"Name" config:{w_code:"Name Surname"} ){ id name config } }`

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much!  I´ve tried your suggested mutation and it worked, but when I try to insert the rest or arguments appears the error again.

Comment: The complet data to insert into config column will be something like that: [{"w_name": "Name","w_code": "001","workplace": "Location","job": "Job","garments": [{"name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 2},{"name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 2},{ "name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 1},{"name": "name","size": "M","quantity": 2}]},{"w_name": "Name","w_code": "002","workplace": "Location","job": "Job","garments": [{"name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 2},{"name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 2},{"name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 1},{"name": "name","size": "M","quantity": 2}]}]

Comment: Hi again! I´m using this JSON scalar https://gist.github.com/lorado/0519972d6fcf01f1aa5179d09eb6a315. I´ve tried to modify parseLiteral function and the mutation changed, but I wasn´t able to get successful response. Can you help me, please?

Comment: that is not a valid JSON. it should start with { }, not with [ ], so put it like `{fields: [{"w_name": "Name","w_code": "001","workplace": "Location","job": "Job","garments": [{"name": "name","size": "L","quantity": 2}, ... ]}] }`

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I get the same error: "Field \"createOrderTemplate\" argument \"config\" requires type JSON!, found {fields: [{w_name: \"Name\", w_code: \"001\", workplace: \"Location\", job: \"Job\", garments: [{name: \"name\", size: \"L\", quantity: 2}, {name: \"name\", size: \"L\", quantity: 2}]}, {w_name: \"Name\", w_code: \"001\", workplace: \"Location\", job: \"Job\", garments: [{name: \"name\", size: \"L\", quantity: 2}, {name: \"name\", size: \"L\", quantity: 2}]}]}; array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\NodeList given"

Comment: Could it be related to the parseLiteral function of the JSON.php file?

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort and time invested to help me :)

Comment: Nice, you're welcome! Checkout this library, that implements a JSON scalar: https://github.com/mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars